# How to parse specific line in a text file in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, file-io, text-parsing, string-parsing

I need to parse a specific lines in a text file in which to begin by a specific words as in the following image :

[image]

I need to parse the lines that begins by "Level" only and extract the value of "Row" and "Col" only. 
Note that the text file will contain 6 groups of such data where each group starts by

> ---------------- chromosome : # ------------------

See the following sample :  [Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qz9agm5e2yrhej/TreeParser.txt?dl=0)

I need to save each group's row and columns in a separated list for each!!. 
Is there any way to perform this ?

I tried the following method :

```
public List<int[,]> getValuesFromTextFile(String filePath ) {

     IEnumerable<string> allLines = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

     List<int[,]> path = new List<int[,]>();

     int[,] item = new int[2,1];

    if (File.Exists(filePath))

        {
                    //Read all content of the files and store it to the list split with new line 
                    allLines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
        }
 
                    //all Level lines
                IEnumerable<string> levelLines = allLines.Where(d => d.StartsWith("Level", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
 
                foreach(string line in levelLines)

                {
                     string[] values= line.Split(':');//either space or tab or others as your file contain seperator  

                     for(int i=1; i <values.Length;i++)  {

                     string value = values[i];// skip index 0,it contains label, remaining are point data

                     if (i == 3) item[1,0] = Int32.Parse(value);

                     if (i == 5 && item[1,0] != null ) { item[0,0] = Int32.Parse(value);
                          path.Add(item);

                          }

                 }

        }



                return path;

        }
```

I got the following error at line( `if (i == 3) item[1,0] = Int32.Parse(value);` ) :

> Input string was not in a correct format.

When I put a break point at this line I saw that the value of string "value" equal to null!!.

When I added a break point to see all lines list contents, I got as in the following image :

[image]

The above method needs to parse each group of levels separately!!.

Comment: You error is clear. `value` doesn't contain a string that can be converted to an int. Put a break-point and see what it is.

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint and post what you see?

Comment: So, you know now where this error comes from

Comment: @L.B : I've updated my question . . .

Comment: I'd recommend you switch to using regex for this. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx You'll have a way easier time parsing text that way.

Comment: @Slepz of course, if we ignore the learning curve of regex :)

Comment: @L.B I suppose... if this is a one off though, here's a query that will give you all the results: "Level.*?Row : '(\d\d?).*?Col : '(\d\d?)"

Comment: @Slepz what about groups? `Chromosome : #`

Comment: what do you mean by this `extract the value of "Row" and "Col"`? You need to store the value in a list separately of row value and Column value?

Comment: @reds : the numbers after them ...

Comment: Ok ill try some..

Comment: Please use an open pastebin service instead of your private Dropbox for storing sample text

Comment: @PaulMcG : There is a bug in the accepted answer, could you read the comments and check the problem please. I tried but I could not guess the problem where ...

Comment: The numeric fields that you specify as `[0-9]` all will match only a single digit. Change all to `[0-9]+`.

Comment: @PaulMcG : By this way we will not get the maximum # of generated rows and columns from levels equal to 10 items for the list only ??

Comment: `'[0-9]+'` will match 1 or more digits in quotes, and many of the values in quotes are 2 digits. Previously all these would not be matched. But this will also match single digits in quotes. Otherwise, I don't fully understand your comment.

Comment: To get the max value, you will need to convert the strings to ints, of course, since lexically '10' < '9'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a named group Regex to parse the lines and build out a list of records.

```
void Main()
{
    var file = File.ReadLines(@"C:\TreeParser.txt");

    var groupRegex = new Regex(@"Chromosome : (?<Chromosome>[0-9])");
    var recordRegex = new Regex(@"Level : '(?<Level>[0-9])', Row : '(?<Row>[0-9])', Col : '(?<Col>[0-9])'");

    var groups = new List<Group>();

    foreach (var line in file)
    {
        var groupMatch = groupRegex.Match(line);
        if (groupMatch.Success)
        {
            groups.Add(new Group
            {
                Chromosome = int.Parse(groupMatch.Groups["Chromosome"].Value),
                Records = new List<Record>()
            });
        }

        var recordMatch = recordRegex.Match(line);
        if (!recordMatch.Success)
        {
            // No match was found
            continue;
        }

        var level = new Record
        {
            Level = int.Parse(recordMatch.Groups["Level"].Value),
            Row = int.Parse(recordMatch.Groups["Row"].Value),
            Col = int.Parse(recordMatch.Groups["Col"].Value)
        };

        groups.Last().Records.Add(level);
    }

    // groups now contains a list of each section from the file with a list of records
}

public class Record
{
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Col { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Chromosome { get; set; }
    public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: See the question `The above method needs to parse each group of levels separately!!.`

Comment: We need to have 6 lists as in the sample text file

Comment: @Rose I updated my answer to break the records out into the 6 groups.

Comment: @Connor :     Your answer gives incomplete results :: see the following sample here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j7s1n5wk6d91oqi/AADtj8SE4u2LbPmrDNgDUeIZa?dl=0 ---> thank u very much. Could you help me to complete this issue?!!. :)

Comment: @Connor : Kindly check  recordRegex  because not all records is stored in some groups !!. I tried to guess where is the problem but I could not because I am not so much in regex!!.

Comment: @Connor : it seems that the maximum number of items that can be stored in the Records list is 10 !.

Answer (score 2):

Rose, you have two problems. First, splitting the text into groups, second parsing each line. 2nd one can easily be done with regex but I will use a json trick using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) :)

```
int groupInx = 0;
var groupLines = File.ReadLines(@"d:\temp\a.txt")
                .GroupBy(x => x.Contains("Chromosome") ? ++groupInx : groupInx);

foreach(var group in groupLines)
{
    var lines = group.Skip(2) //skip ----- lines
                    .Select(x => JObject.Parse($"{{{x}}}"))
                    .ToList();

    //use a loop for each lines here
    int level = (int)lines[0]["Level"]; //for example
    int col = (int)lines[0]["Col"]; //for example

}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of [0] in the last two lines ?

Comment: just to show the content of the first line of each group. Write a loop there and use its index like `i`

Comment: Of course, I posted its link in my answer. Forget my answer. It seems that this conversation will continue forever.

Comment: How to add this reference to my solution, I've download it but I could not use it or install it into my solution (VS 2010)

Comment: @Rose Open the zip file then see the Solution explorer tree, right click on *references*, choose *add reference* and *browse*. (You can also do the same thing using *Manage nuget packages*, just search for Json.Net in its form and install it)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
   List<RowAndCol> lstrc = new List<RowAndCol>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var file = File.ReadLines("E:\\SAMPLE_FILE\\sample.txt");

        var getList = (from f in file.ToList() where f.Contains("Level") || f.Contains("Chromosome") select f).ToList();
        int cnt = 1;

        string chr = string.Empty;
            foreach (var fl in getList.ToList())
            {

                RowAndCol rl = new RowAndCol();
                if (fl.Contains("Level"))
                {
                    String[] s = fl.Split(',');
                    String[] rowValue = s[1].Trim().Split(':');
                    String[] colValue = s[2].Trim().Split(':');

                    rl.Chromosome = chr;
                    rl.rownum = cnt;
                    rl.rowtext = "Row";
                    rl.coltext = "Col";
                    rl.row = rowValue[1].ToString();
                    rl.col = colValue[1].ToString();

                    cnt += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    chr = fl.ToString();
                }

                lstrc.Add(rl);
            }
            cnt = 1;
    }
    public class RowAndCol
    {
        public int rownum { get; set; }
        public string Chromosome { get; set; }
        public String rowtext { get; set; }
        public String coltext { get; set; }
        public String row { get;set; }
        public String col { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: No one reads previous comments anymore before posting answers? What about groups?

Comment: My bad forgot the groups.. ill update it later thanks @L.B

Comment: as far as i analyzed the sample text content the group is in ascending order. Updated the answer above

Comment: it's in every row has its own count for every group of chromosome.

Comment: Don't you think lambda notation is easier sometimes. For ex using `file.Where(f=> f.Contains("Level"))` instead of `from f in file.ToList() where f.Contains("Level") select f`

Comment: I'm just a neophyte for lambda expression.. Just sharing my answer.. thanks

Comment: @L.B Maybe my way of using that code because i'm a Database Lover.. It seems like just a little bit difference than query itself. But thanks for giving me that way of Coding.